# Migrate web application to PHP Framework

Tags: php, frameworks

The company i work for are looking to move their php web application over to a framework. I personally haven't had much experience with php frameworks at all, so i need to read up on them and learn which ones are best.

My question is, is there a quick way to migrate a standard php/css/html web application over to a framework without having to rewrite a lot of it?

If not, what are some good reputable companies that do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This belongs on a different network. I accidentally marked as spam, as it is not.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no quick way to migrate the application.  Start with a requirements review, you may find that a robust CMS or cart will provide a lot of the features you need.